# How to return by for loop python?

Tags: python, inheritance, return

I have a parent class and two child class. I can create one object from any class my program run without Error. But when use `add_emp` method of Manager class, objects added to emp list but when use `print_emp` method objects that was add to list not return!!!!

```
class Emplyee:

increaspay = 1.09
def __init__(self, fname, lname, email,pay):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.email = email
    self.pay = pay


def Fullname(self):
    print(f'{self.fname} {self.lname}')


def Applypay(self):
    print(f'NewPay = {int(self.pay*Emplyee.increaspay)}')


class Developer(Emplyee):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, email, pay, lang):
        super().__init__(fname, lname, email, pay)
        self.lang = lang

class Manager(Emplyee):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, email, pay, emps=None):
        super().__init__(fname, lname, email, pay)
        if emps is None:
            self.emps = []
        else:
            self.emps = emps
    
    def add_emp(self, emp):
        if emp not in self.emps:
            self.emps.append(emp)
           

    def remove_emp(self, emp):
        if emp in self.emps:
            self.emps.remove(emp)

    def print_emp(self):
        for emp in self.emps:
            return (emp.Fullname())
```

Comment: What do you want it to do?  Do you want to return a list of all the full names?  You can  do  `return list(emp.Fullname() for emp in self.emps)`  Or, you can keep the loop you have, and change `return` to `yield`.

Comment: i write loop in print_emp loop for return all emp in emps list but not return all mmember of list and just return first mmember of list!!

Comment: I know exactly what it DOES.  What I asked is what you WANTED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `return [emp.Fullname() for emp in self.emps]`.

In `print_emp(self):` clause of your code, python loops over `self.emps`. That is, it *first* sets `emps` to be the first item of `self.emps`. So `emp.Fullname()` initially is the name of the first employee. Now when python sees `return`, it returns this `emp.Fullname()`, and just **finishes the method**. This is why your code returns only the name of the first employee.